# I have a pump, I am trying to see if it can push a underwater submarine, the details are down below

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have a pump, I am trying to see if it can push an underwater submarine.

So the pump can push water at 10l/minute, its output valve is 6mm in diameter and the input valve is 1 cm in diameter. The power it takes is about 8 W and H-max is 5m, the body it is pushing has a frontal diameter of 12 cm.

How can I find out at what speed this pump can push the submarine?

Comment: You gave the frontal diameter, but not the shape.  Shape has a big impact on drag coefficient.  Also, you need to specify the mass flow rate of the pump and the velocity of the water that exits the output valve in order to determine the propulsive force.  As stated, your problem can't be answered because there is not enough data to evaluate it.

Comment: If I had those parameters then how would I find the propulsive force. For now just the propulsive force?

Comment: The mass flow rate of exiting water multiplied by the exit velocity of the exiting water gives you propulsive force.  The submarine will accelerate until the drag force equals the propulsive force, and that drag force depends on the drag coefficient.  When the two forces are equal, there is no net force on the submarine and its velocity is constant.

Comment: Okay so I have made this calculation, can you please help check if I did it correctly. So the pump has 240l/hour and has a valve diameter of 5mm. Therefore the volume of a cylindrical column of the pump of length 1cm is going to be (0.5/2)^2*pi*1                                                                                                  which is 0.196 cm^3. 240l/h is 66.667 cm^3/second. There for the time taken for 0.196 cm^3 is going to be 0.003 seconds. So it takes 0.003 seconds for a column of water 1cm long to exit the pump. That is 1cm/0.003 seconds which is 3.333m/s.

Comment: 3.333 m/s times mass flow rate is the propulsive force. So 3.333* 997*0.24/3600 where 997 is the density of water 0.24 m^3 and 3600 seconds (240l/hour) which is 22.156 newton?

Comment: Units REALLY matter.  Example.  mass flow rate (kg/s) multiplied by velocity (m/s) yields $(kg)(m)/s^2$.  A slight rearrangement yields $kg(m/s^2)$ which is $ma$ which equals force.